# How to disable Windows 10 NTFS write lock due to faulty "Fast startup" option from other Ubuntu machine

Tags: dual-boot, windows, drive, read-only

Suituation: Windows 10 itself is broken and wouldn't startup anyhow. I have Ubuntu 18 Machine. The drive is absolutely healthy but mounts in readonly mode. I've managed to find out that in happens due to special Windows 10 feature called "Fast startup" (may be I'm wrong). Anyway. There are many answers that in general begin with something like "Boot your Windows...". But I cant't, its totaly ruined and ends up with BSOD.

Comment: If you're going to reinstall or repair Windows you'll be able to disable that setting. If you do not intend to keep that Windows then just backup the files you want and format the drive.

Comment: Your drive (hardware) may be fine, but you're getting read-only mount's because your file-system (logical data-system on drive) is in an inconsistent state (fast-boot on windows is a form of hibernate-restore, some data is kept in the restore/fast-boot file & not on filesystem itself). It's proprietary (how fast-boot works, how fs-data not on fs but in fastboot files is stored) so it must be fixed by windows. I agree with GabrielaGarcia - grab the data off, format it (so you have a clean file-system) then restore data, if you don't/can't fix it by installation into another windows system etc.

Comment: If a had a spare drive, it would not be a question at all?